# Moving complex object along bezier path

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, opengl

I am fairly new to blender and am using it to model things that I am loading into OpenGL. I am modeling this logo:

[image]

I am also animating the gears, which I have done already. I modeled the gears in Blender, which turned out awesome!

Now I am moving onto the chain... The chain is something that is going to be too hard to animate using OpenGL, and so I am hoping I can do something tricky in Blender. What I am hoping to accomplish is modeling the gear 4-5 times in Blender and then just showing different models at different times to make it look as if the gear is moving. So what I am hoping to do here is to model the gear once, export the obj file, move it a little, export the obj... ect.

Is it possible to do something like this in Blender?

Comment: Did you consider using OpenCollada. In theory it should be possible to export object, meshes and animation and import it into your OpenGL application (there is library for loading OpenCollada files). https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/OpenCOLLADA

Comment: Well, you could get the chain to wrap by applying an Array mod, set it follow the curve, then you could just move it everywhere you needed and it'd all follow.